# In A Great Trouble With My Themes

Tags: magento2

I am using `Magento 2.2.` I'm in a great Trouble with my themes, I've installed 3 themes but now i want to delete them all and roll back to my default Luma!

Then I want to reinstall it again!!!

what to do? I've already looked for how to deleted them but, i couldn't able to find theme folder database!
Or any direct code to rollback all themes to default 
Or way I could reset my theme! 
And take a not that, In my phpmyadmin there is no such database named theme! What to do?

Answer (score 0):

go in the backend and assign your luma theme for the global scope from the screen at Content/Configuration

--> This step should be sufficient to setup luma

If you can't do the above, you may try to rename the file `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/registration.php`
to registration.php.bak for instance

and after that, flush the cache php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: and I also want to remove current customed theme and then again want to reinstall them!